# mainframe - FOLLOWING RESERVED DATA SET NAMES UNAVAILABLE TO userid

Tags: mainframe, jcl, dfsort

I'm trying to create a report from a VSAM KSDS. I got this error when run the job

```
 IEF861I FOLLOWING RESERVED DATA SET NAMES UNAVAILABLE TO SHE02
 IEF863I DSN = SHECICS.ZEUSBANK.BRANCHES SHE00081 RC = 04 RSN 2
 IEF099I JOB SHE00081 WAITING FOR DATA SETS
```

Here's my code

```
 //SHE0008  JOB A492,PROGRAMMER                           
 //STEP01   EXEC PGM=ICETOOL                              
 //SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                   
 //SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                   
 //INPUT1   DD DSN=SHECICS.ZEUSBANK.BRANCHES,DISP=SHR     
 //SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                                   
 //SYSIN    DD *                                          
      DISPLAY FROM(INPUT1) LIST(REPORT)                   
      TITLE('LIST OF ZEUSBANK BRANCH')                    
      HEADER('SORTCODE') ON (1,4,ZD)                      
      HEADER('FLAG') ON (10,1,CH)                         
      HEADER('BRANCH NAME') ON (20,32,CH)                 
 /*
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dastaset is in use by another address space/job/task and has an **enque** on it.

Considering the dataset name it could well be in use by **CICS**.

- You can try again later, it may have been released.
- You could talk to you local friendly system's programmers who may tell you what has the enque.
- You could try issuing the `D GRS,RES=(SYSDSN,'SHECICS.ZEUSBANK.BRANCHES')` command.

You may find [IEF863I](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ieam800/gg863i.htm) of interest.

Comment: I submitted load of jobs, is there any way to kill them all?

Comment: I'm in ZeusPlex TSO anyway

Comment: @TriNguyen [CANCEL command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ieag100/cancel.htm)